# My new tablet tells me that I am making a wrong pattern and I am not able to use it

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

I have been given by a EE shop an Android on contract. Brand new it came in a sealed box. I went home, nuwrapped the box, got the tablet, put the sim in ant switch it on. I was confronted with a new type of request  for me that up to now I’ve always used Apple: it asked me to digit a pattern to join some dots distributed on the screen. I have never been faced with such request and I joined few dots randomly. I never pressed any save or done ani thing to record that setting. I then tried to do it again, after I understood that the pattern would be my password to access the gadget, but as soon as two Frits were jointed together the tablet told me that it was wrong please try again.  I went to EE Shop and the staff just patronised me and told me that it is not their problem. Now I am left with a new tablet that I am paying for monthly and no way to make use of it

Answer (score 3):

What actually happened there is that:
You were setting up the tablet and it asked you to set a pattern for unlock.

*You then drew the pattern and repeated the same on reprompt. It got accepted and saved.*

**Now, you need to draw the same pattern to unlock the tablet.**

Here's what you can do if you have forgotten the pattern that you have initially drawn:
Go into the recovery mode and perform a factory reset. Now, since this is an unknown tablet, running on gingerbread, I cannot suggest the exact key combination to enter the recovery mode. So, just keep on trying all these combinations one after other *when the tablet is powered off*.

**Note:** Press and hold the keys mentioned.

```
Volume Down + Power
Volume Up + Power
Volume Up + Power + Home
Volume Down + Power + Volume Up
Home + Power
```

In the recovery mode, you will get the options for wipe or factory reset. Just do it and your tablet should start from fresh. Be sure to read the instructions while setting it up this time.

If you know the manufacturer of the tablet, then please try searching their website or directly on Google about how to enter the recovery mode on it.